# Building a shape out of two rectangles

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, physics, farseer-physics-engine

I would like to build a body with Farseer out of two rectangles so it looks like this:

[image]

I am a real beginner, so please describe it carefully.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to make the shape out of the texture, but this hasen't worked. But I think the shape is not so complex, so I asked if it is possible to make this with 2 rectange. Making one big rectange works well, but the collision isn't very well, though the corners

Comment: What version of Farseer are you using?

Comment: The newest: 3.3.1

Comment: Create two rectangle fixtures, and attach them to the same body.  One of the fixtures will have a rotation of 90 degrees, in respect to the other fixture.

Comment: how do you do this? I haven't found this in the Farseers Documentation.

Comment: Michael, I've update my answer to show how to do it using `Fixture`s and `Body`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

**1. With Fixtures**
I recommend doing it this way as it's much easier to manage. Here's the code with comments:

```
//Create the initial body + 1 fixture in the shape of a rectangle
// The fixture is 2 world units wide and 1 world unit high
Body body = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 2, 1, density);
//Create a new fixture on the body.
body.CreateFixture(
    //The new fixture is a PolygonShape (CreateFixture accepts a Shape parameter)
    new PolygonShape(
        //This method returns a list of vertices which represent the shape of the fixture.
        //  Note the parameters are HALF width/height and that we've set
        //  it up so it's already "rotated".
        PolygonTools.CreateRectangle(0.5f, 1)
    , density));
//Set up body data
body.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
//Etc...
```

*Note: I've spanned some lines in order to explain what's going on, you obviously don't need to do this.*

**2. With Bodies**
You should also be able to weld two bodies together like this:

```
//Create the first body with a width of 3 and height of 1
Body part1 = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 3, 1, density);
//Create the second body
Body part2 = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 3, 1, density);
//Rotate the body by pi / 2 radians (90 degrees)
part2.Rotation = MathHelper.PiOver2;
//Use a weld joint to stick them together
JointFactory.CreateWeldJoint(world, part1, part2, Vector2.Zero, Vector2.Zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a Body with 2 Fixtures attached if Farseer follows what Box2D does.

I've never used Farseer but the following is what can be done in Box2D and there should be something similar in Farseer:

Create 2 PolygonShapes using function below

```
void SetAsBox(float32 hx, float32 hy); //default centers each fixture at center of body
```

For example `tallRect` and `wideRect` are PolygonShapes

```
tallRect.SetAsBox(1,2);
wideRect.SetAsBox(2,1);
```

Create two Fixtures, one for each shape and attach both shapes to your Body using

```
myBody.CreateFixture(a);
myBody.CreateFixture(b);
```

I created something like this:
[image]